# SQL case unsensitive

Tags: sql, uppercase

Hello i have a table with colums called NAME, in this colum i can have this type of name : First name Uppercase and other lower (Jack), all name uppercase (JACK), and name with space (Jack ) or (JACK ).

How can show all name than have jack in all type ?

i need to search multiple name with IN statement

i use ORACLE

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sniff, sniff... smells like homework ;-)

Comment: Why the need for an `in` statement? You're trying to do a case-insensitive search with truncation. Depending on your DBMS, something like `select name from table where lower(name) like '%jack%';` is much more appropriate.

Comment: and if ii want to put into an inner join ? my db is oracle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE '%jack%'
```

Comment: I forgot  one thing i need to search multiple name with IN statement

Comment: this will not get him the names with upper case jack. You must apply either a ToLower() or ToUpper in Name before using LIKE.

Comment: @Veverke - he said SQL Server, that is case insensitive in the LIKE statement.

Comment: @Hogan: Oh, nice to know. Sorry Simon, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Name 
 FROM Table 
 WHERE UPPER(Name) LIKE '%JACK%'
```

will work in all SQL.  In SQL Server I believe LIKE is case insensitive but it might depend on configuration settings and collation.

or maybe you need

```
 SELECT Name 
 FROM Table 
 WHERE UPPER(TRIM(Name)) IN ('JACK','HOGAN','VICTOR')
```

(replace `TRIM(Name)` with `RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))` if not using SQL Server.)

If you have a table with the list of names you can do it like this:

```
 SELECT Name
 FROM Table 
 JOIN NameTable ON UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Table.Name))) = NameTable.Name
```

Comment: I show you how to use in.  If you have many names to search you should probably put them in a table.

Comment: Select name,A.valueA from tableA inner join tableB on valueA A = valueB and name in ('jack','fred')  the name i take from a txt file

Comment: @v3ctor, really you can't use my example to get this query to work??  geeeeze

Comment: @v3ctor - hint **LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(name))) in ('jack','fred')**

Comment: the name into in statement must be  sometimes with first character Upper (jack,Fred,carl,Laurence)

Comment: @v3ctor - No.  Lower makes it all lower case you only have to check the lower case version.

Comment: if i use LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(name))) in ('jack','Fred') it show me only jack

Comment: @v3ctor - yes because you have to use lower case on the right -- as I said before use `('jack','fred')`.  "Fred" and "FRED" will never match anything if you use lower on the left.